# Using Telephony Manager in android to find IMEI number

Tags: android, imei

I m very new to Android Development.
I want to find the IMEI number of the phone and using "android.telephony.TelephonyManager;".

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Now the compiler says.
Context cannot be resolved to a variable.
Any one can help me ? What step I m missing
I have also included user permission in XML.

Answer (score 22):

Verify your Imports , you should import :  `android.content.Context` ,

And then use this code :

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
// get IMEI
String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
//get The Phone Number
String phone = tm.getLine1Number();
```

Or directly : use this :

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

**EDIT :** **you should pass the context to your new Class on the constructor :**

```
public class YourClass {
    private Context context;

    //the constructor 
    public YourClass( Context _context){

        this.context = _context;
        //other initialisations .....

    }

   //here is your method to get the IMEI Number by using the Context that you passed to your class
   public String getIMEINumber(){
       //...... place your code here 
   }

}
```

And in your Activity , instanciate your class and pass the context to it like this :

```
YourClass instance = new YourClass(this);
String IMEI = instance.getIMEINumber();
```

Comment: its okey now but next time first read question carefully after then give answer in proper way

Comment: i've read the question carefully , i've read it before it has been edited, and the question was : get the IMEI Number and that is not more explicated :)

Comment: he was asked question with sample code which is right now in question but that was not in good format so i just added his question.. but he asked question with sample code.. and one more thing brother I dont want to fight with you I am just suggesting you nothing else..

Comment: lol , me too , i'm not fighting you , come ooon !!! i'm just telling you too that i've read the qustion carrefuly , and thanks for ur suggestions :)

Comment: Thank u all , i didn't imported android.content.Context.

Comment: but now says getSystemService... The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type

Comment: do you call your code at the method onCreate() of your Activity ? if yes , so try to replace the getSystemService() with this.getSystemService(String)

Comment: its working fine on onCreate method of activity. but what i m doing is that this function is called on an another class which i have created

Comment: in this case , you should pass the context to your new class , see my edit

Comment: This is a Context leak, only do it if you know the lifecycle of "YourClass"

Answer (score 9):

Add in this code:

```
 TelephonyManager manager=(TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String deviceid=manager.getDeviceId();

//Device Id is IMEI number

  Log.d("msg", "Device id"+deviceid);
```

Manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Try below piece of code it will help you to get device IMEI number.

```
public String getDeviceID() { 
    String deviceId;   
    TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null) {
            deviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); 
        } else {
            deviceId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
        }
    return deviceId;
}
```

Also give the read phone state permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

just remove `Context` keyword in `Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE` and check

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String IMEI = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

Answer (score 1):

For Compiler error "Context cannot be resolved to a variable", make sure you have imported `android.content.Context` package. 
In Eclipse, quick fixes would have it when you move mouse pointer over the error line in code.
 And make sure you have added `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission Manifiest file.

Answer (score 0):

**[In case if anyone still stumbles here looking for this still existing age-old solution]**

AFAIK, TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() is not reliable due to various constraints from operators.
There are some java reflection based hacks but varies from device to device thus making those hacks sort of useless [at least in terms of supported models]

But there is a legitimate lawful logic to find the number, if you really need so. Query all the SMS by sms provider and get the "To" number.

Extra benefits of this trick: 1. you can get all the line numbers if there is multi sim in the device.

Cons: 1. you will need SMS_READ permission [sorry for that]
 2. You will get all the sim numbers ever used in the device. this problem can be minimized with some constraint logic e.g. time frame (sms received or sent only today) etc. It would be  interesting to hear from others about how to improve this case.