# Android how to avoid NullPointException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have NullPointException in my code, and this is the reason why my app is crashing...
I'm new in Android development, so can you please help me to avoid this Null exception?

here is some code, where i think is this error:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    btn_skip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    // get data
    String email_txt = email.getEditableText().toString();
    String confirme_email = confirm_email.getEditableText().toString();

    //get IMEI
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

    if (v == btn_skip)
    {
        sendPostRequest(null, null, imei);
    }
    //if email is not valid then show errors
    else if (!checkEmail(email.getText().toString()) && v == btn_get_access)
    {
        email_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        email.requestFocus();
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "lkdjfgkdjg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //else if (!confirme_email.equals(email_txt) && v == btn_get_access)
    else if (!email_txt.equals(confirme_email))
    {
        email_confirm_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        confirm_email.requestFocus();
    }
    else 
    {
        email_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        email_confirm_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sendPostRequest(email_txt, confirme_email, imei);
    }
}
```

so how i get this error:
in my app i have 2 activities, and i can switch them by buttons, first button send some data which i get from user on the server (all inputs are filled with data), with the second button i can skip the input filling and go to the second screen(all inputs are empty);
from the 2nd screen i can go back to the first screen without any data(and when i press this back button, i have this null exception).
Please help me with this error, because i can't imagine how to avoid it...

**UPD LOGCAT**

```
03-05 10:01:07.214: W/ActivityThread(12011): Application com.vladimir.expert_suise is      waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
03-05 10:01:07.224: I/System.out(12011): Sending WAIT chunk
03-05 10:01:07.224: I/dalvikvm(12011): Debugger is active
03-05 10:01:07.424: I/System.out(12011): Debugger has connected
03-05 10:01:07.424: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:07.624: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...

03-05 10:01:07.814: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:08.014: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:08.215: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:08.415: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:08.615: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:08.815: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:09.015: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:09.226: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:09.426: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:09.626: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:09.826: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:10.026: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:10.226: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:10.427: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:10.627: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:10.827: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:11.027: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:11.227: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:11.428: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:11.628: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:11.828: I/System.out(12011): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:01:12.028: I/System.out(12011): debugger has settled (1463)
03-05 10:01:13.620: D/libEGL(12011): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
03-05 10:01:13.800: D/libEGL(12011): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-05 10:01:14.080: D/libEGL(12011): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-05 10:01:14.080: D/libEGL(12011): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-05 10:01:14.401: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12011): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-05 10:01:14.561: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x520a0000 size:1536000 fd:61
03-05 10:01:14.591: D/OpenGLRenderer(12011): Enabling debug mode 0
03-05 10:01:15.141: D/OpenGLRenderer(12011): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:01:15.171: D/OpenGLRenderer(12011): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:01:15.211: D/OpenGLRenderer(12011): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:01:15.281: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5251a000 size:1536000 fd:64
03-05 10:01:15.962: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52691000 size:1536000 fd:67
03-05 10:01:19.996: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12011): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-05 10:01:20.006: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52b08000 size:1536000 fd:76
03-05 10:01:20.316: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52cff000 size:1536000 fd:79
03-05 10:01:20.647: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12011): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-05 10:01:20.657: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52f76000 size:1536000 fd:82
03-05 10:01:20.797: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x530ed000 size:1536000 fd:88
03-05 10:01:20.957: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53264000 size:1536000 fd:91
03-05 10:01:21.157: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x533db000 size:1536000 fd:94
03-05 10:01:21.177: D/OpenGLRenderer(12011): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-05 10:01:21.207: D/OpenGLRenderer(12011): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-05 10:01:22.999: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12011): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-05 10:01:23.019: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5251a000 size:1536000 fd:63
03-05 10:01:23.309: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52691000 size:1536000 fd:69
03-05 10:01:23.419: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12011): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-05 10:01:23.429: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52a08000 size:1536000 fd:79
03-05 10:01:23.610: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52cff000 size:1536000 fd:88
03-05 10:01:23.660: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x530ed000 size:1536000 fd:97
03-05 10:01:23.830: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53552000 size:1536000 fd:100
03-05 10:01:23.850: D/OpenGLRenderer(12011): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-05 10:01:23.870: D/OpenGLRenderer(12011): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-05 10:01:25.291: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12011): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-05 10:01:25.301: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5261a000 size:1536000 fd:63
03-05 10:01:25.451: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52e76000 size:1536000 fd:82
03-05 10:01:25.481: D/OpenGLRenderer(12011): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-05 10:01:25.882: D/memalloc(12011): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52a08000 size:1536000 fd:79
03-05 10:01:27.603: D/AndroidRuntime(12011): Shutting down VM
03-05 10:01:27.603: W/dalvikvm(12011): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ad9228)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at com.vladimir.expert_suise.FirstScreen.onClick(FirstScreen.java:174)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14400)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-05 10:01:27.633: E/AndroidRuntime(12011):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 10:01:30.747: D/Process(12011): killProcess, pid=12011
03-05 10:01:30.757: D/Process(12011): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
03-05 10:01:30.757: D/Process(12011): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
03-05 10:01:30.757: D/Process(12011): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:788)
03-05 10:01:30.757: D/Process(12011): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:104)
03-05 10:01:30.757: D/Process(12011): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
03-05 10:01:30.757: D/Process(12011): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
03-05 10:01:30.757: D/Process(12011): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 10:01:30.757: I/Process(12011): Sending signal. PID: 12011 SIG: 9
03-05 10:01:31.307: D/libEGL(12216): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
03-05 10:01:31.307: D/libEGL(12216): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-05 10:01:31.307: D/libEGL(12216): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-05 10:01:31.317: D/libEGL(12216): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-05 10:01:31.337: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12216): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-05 10:01:31.357: D/memalloc(12216): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51fa0000 size:1536000 fd:61
03-05 10:01:31.367: D/OpenGLRenderer(12216): Enabling debug mode 0
03-05 10:01:31.417: D/OpenGLRenderer(12216): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:01:31.437: D/OpenGLRenderer(12216): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:01:31.467: D/OpenGLRenderer(12216): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:01:31.507: D/memalloc(12216): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5241a000 size:1536000 fd:64
03-05 10:01:31.918: D/memalloc(12216): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52691000 size:1536000 fd:67
03-05 10:01:47.313: D/AndroidRuntime(12216): Shutting down VM
03-05 10:01:47.313: W/dalvikvm(12216): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ad9228)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at com.vladimir.expert_suise.FirstScreen.onClick(FirstScreen.java:174)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14400)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-05 10:01:47.313: E/AndroidRuntime(12216):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 10:01:49.064: D/Process(12216): killProcess, pid=12216
03-05 10:01:49.064: D/Process(12216): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
03-05 10:01:49.064: D/Process(12216): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
03-05 10:01:49.064: D/Process(12216): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:788)
03-05 10:01:49.064: D/Process(12216): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:104)
03-05 10:01:49.064: D/Process(12216): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
03-05 10:01:49.064: D/Process(12216): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
03-05 10:01:49.064: D/Process(12216): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 10:01:49.064: I/Process(12216): Sending signal. PID: 12216 SIG: 9
03-05 10:01:49.545: D/libEGL(12233): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
03-05 10:01:49.555: D/libEGL(12233): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-05 10:01:49.555: D/libEGL(12233): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-05 10:01:49.555: D/libEGL(12233): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-05 10:01:49.575: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12233): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-05 10:01:49.585: D/memalloc(12233): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51fb9000 size:1536000 fd:62
03-05 10:01:49.585: D/OpenGLRenderer(12233): Enabling debug mode 0
03-05 10:01:49.645: D/OpenGLRenderer(12233): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:01:49.665: D/OpenGLRenderer(12233): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:01:49.685: D/OpenGLRenderer(12233): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:01:49.755: D/memalloc(12233): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52466000 size:1536000 fd:65
03-05 10:01:50.135: D/memalloc(12233): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x526dd000 size:1536000 fd:68
03-05 10:01:51.347: D/OpenGLRenderer(12233): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-05 10:01:51.447: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12233): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-05 10:01:51.447: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12233): InputConnection = com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@40dd02e8, active client = false
03-05 10:01:51.647: D/OpenGLRenderer(12233): Flushing caches (mode 1)
03-05 10:02:00.155: D/OpenGLRenderer(12233): Flushing caches (mode 1)
03-05 10:02:08.814: D/OpenGLRenderer(12233): Flushing caches (mode 1)
03-05 10:02:08.994: D/OpenGLRenderer(12233): Flushing caches (mode 2)
03-05 10:02:32.427: W/ActivityThread(12468): Application com.vladimir.expert_suise is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
03-05 10:02:32.447: I/System.out(12468): Sending WAIT chunk
03-05 10:02:32.447: I/dalvikvm(12468): Debugger is active
03-05 10:02:32.647: I/System.out(12468): Debugger has connected
03-05 10:02:32.647: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:32.847: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:33.047: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:33.247: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:33.448: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:33.648: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:33.848: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:34.048: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:34.248: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:34.449: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:34.649: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:34.859: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:35.049: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:35.249: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:35.450: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:35.650: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:35.850: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:36.050: I/System.out(12468): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-05 10:02:36.250: I/System.out(12468): debugger has settled (1356)
03-05 10:02:37.502: D/libEGL(12468): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
03-05 10:02:37.532: D/libEGL(12468): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-05 10:02:37.582: D/libEGL(12468): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-05 10:02:37.582: D/libEGL(12468): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-05 10:02:37.652: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12468): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-05 10:02:37.692: D/memalloc(12468): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x520a0000 size:1536000 fd:61
03-05 10:02:37.702: D/OpenGLRenderer(12468): Enabling debug mode 0
03-05 10:02:37.902: D/OpenGLRenderer(12468): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:02:37.922: D/OpenGLRenderer(12468): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:02:37.952: D/OpenGLRenderer(12468): has fontRender patch
03-05 10:02:38.002: D/memalloc(12468): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5251a000 size:1536000 fd:64
03-05 10:02:38.312: D/memalloc(12468): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52691000 size:1536000 fd:67
03-05 10:03:07.731: D/dalvikvm(12468): Debugger has detached; object registry had 776 entries
03-05 10:03:07.731: D/AndroidRuntime(12468): Shutting down VM
03-05 10:03:07.731: W/dalvikvm(12468): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ad9228)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at com.vladimir.expert_suise.FirstScreen.onClick(FirstScreen.java:174)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14400)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-05 10:03:07.731: E/AndroidRuntime(12468):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post log.cat there we can see where the exception happens

Comment: Could you share the logs from logcat ?

Comment: @Gjordis I have updated my question with logcat

Comment: which is 174 line in FirstScreen.java

Comment: @Chintan Rathod
`TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove `Context` like this:

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String IMEI = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

taken from [Using Telephony Manager in android to find IMEI number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514163/using-telephony-manager-in-android-to-find-imei-number)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken permission in manifest file??

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: wouldn't be a NPE but rather a IllegalStateException.

Comment: Yes, i have this permission