# How to get IMEI in Android using code

Tags: android, android-intent, imei

I am trying to get IMEI of a phone by running this android code

```
String imei="*#06#";//Checking the Phone's IMEI.
Intent cintent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode(imei)));
startActivity(cintent);
```

I have set the permission as required

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

But am getting this feedback on my phone "Connection problem or invalid MMI code".
Where did I go wrong? Thanks

Comment: please elaborate what you want exactly..?

Comment: To simplify the process of getting an IMEI of an android phone by a touch of a button, instead of dialing the code

Comment: [Try out this link it will help you to get device IMEI number](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33471248/2183890)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple change of this line did the magic. From

```
    Intent.ACTION_CALL
```

TO:

```
    Intent.ACTION_DIAL
```

Thanks