# IMEI Number on non-network devices

Tags: android, imei

I'm currently working on an application where the code uses the device IMEI number as a variable to store something in the DB. We need to see what device the reading originated from.

ie:
String IMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

However, I'm not sure how this will behave on phones without network access, such as a wifi only tablet. Will is return a unique value? Will it return null?

I know there are alternatives to using IMEI, and I don't need any explanation on what alternative values I can use. I only need to know what will happen when I call this on a phone with no network access. Please do not provide suggestions on alternative IDs or anything other than what I have asked. I appreciate you taking the time to read this question.

Thanks,
-Mark

Comment: [Try out this link may be it will help you to get device IMEI number](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33471248/2183890)

Comment: "I know there are alternatives to using IMEI, and I don't need any explanation on what alternative values I can use. I only need to know what will happen when I call this on a phone with no network access. Please do not provide suggestions on alternative IDs or anything other than what I have asked. I appreciate you taking the time to read this question."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `null`.

Just ran into this on an app I wrote 3 years ago, and only just converted to tablet format. I had forgotten we were using IMEI (against the advice you and I both received ;-) ) and we started sending a whole bunch of null device IDs to the server.

Sadly it took a whole lot of network logs before I tracked it down to that little hack.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I will have to make changes to accommodate.

Comment: I wish I could give you recommendations based on the various alternatives, as to what works well, but we haven't implemented an alternative yet. Client has placed this on the backlog for further server development, and in the meantime we are excluding tablets from the roll-out.

Comment: what did you use instead IMEI?

Comment: @jcesar I have not implemented the fix yet (we have removed tablets from out target audience for now). However, check out info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device and http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html